# VirtualGL and TurboVNC: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0"

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, nvidia

I have a remote computer on AWS with Nvidia GRID card K520 and want to remotely render 3D graphics. I use Ubuntu 14.04 - 64 bit. Remote and local.
For remote connection and OpenGL rendering we use VirtualGL and TurboVNC (*amd64.deb).

I properly installed VirtualGL and TurboVNC and I have Nvidia drivers.

As I understand VirtualGL uses display :0 and TurboVNC uses display :1 on remote machine.

When I connect to the remote machine and I want to run a 3D app (via vglrun ) it gives me error:

extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".

I don't undrestand how VirtualGL works on a remote machine with TurboVNC, how it uses the display :0 and if it's ok.

Do I need something to setup (.conf, graphic driver). I tried installing it over and over, tried serching for answer, but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: I'm facing the exact problem, still not able to solve it

Comment: can you post your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` from your remote machine?

Comment: I found the solution, thank you much for the interest!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Found the solution**

**I. Recap**

The remote computer on AWS (EC2 gl2.2xlarge) is running on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04. I properly installed VirtualGL, TurboVNC and Nvidia 352.63 drivers (cuda 7.0).

1. I remotely connected to the aws instance.
2. Run the TurboVNC server: 
   `/opt/TurboVNC/bin/vncserver`
3. Run TurboVNC client and connect to remote computer: 
   `/opt/TurboVNC/bin/vncviewer`
4. When I wanted to run application on the remote pc there was the error.
   `/opt/VirtualGL/bin/vglrun <application>`

Error: extension “GLX” missing on display “:0.0”

**II. Solution**

4. First type on remote pc:
   `sudo xinit &`
5. Run application on remote pc
   `/opt/VirtualGL/bin/vglrun <application>`

Example:
`/opt/VirtualGL/bin/vglrun glxgears`

**sudo xinit &**

What does `sudo xinit &` ?

To get OpenGL applications to run on the remote computer I need to start a second X Server which VirtualGL uses to talk to the NVIDIA gpu. The second X Server will start with the `sudo xinit &`.

**Some useful checks**

1. Check VGA devices on comp: `lspci | grep VGA`

This shows on AWS (EC2 gl2.2xlarge) with Nvidia GRID card K520:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Cirrus Logic GD 5446
00:03.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104GL [GRID K520] (rev a1)
```

2. Check drivers: `nvidia-smi`

If it show some useful information, then the drivers are working:

NVIDIA-SMI 352.63

Driver Version: 352.63

**Some useful info from xorg.conf (/etc/X11/xorg.conf)**

```
Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BusID          "0:3:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device1"
Driver         "vesa"
BusID          "0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
SubSection     "Display"
Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection
```